# How to make loop inside a string

Tags: php

I just want to ask to you, How to make a loop on a string, like this code bellow...

```
$array = array("a", "B", "c", "D");

$loop = "
foreach($array as $ray):
echo $ray;
endforeach;
";
```

Note :
I am using email function that the body of email should inside of the string,
like this

```
$val = "A";
$to = "bla@bla.com";
$from = "ha@bla.com";
$subject = " bla bla bla";
$body = "
Hahahah
hahaa
$val
";
```

Comment: "On a string"? Do you mean, the loop is inside of the string and is evaluated, there is a loop that generates the string... Why exactly do you need the loop inside of the string?

Comment: Can you explain that why do you need a loop **inside** a string. Usually we use loops to create strings. If you explain in detail what do you need probably we can find a better solution

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you just want to echo "aBcD" or make $loop = "aBcD"?

Comment: I am using email function, so that's way I should  loop inside of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have something called `Anonymous functions`. It's really cool: [read the manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

I don't know what you want to reach, but to get a function in a variable, you can use this. Here is an example of what you have but using `Anonymous functions`.

```
<?php
$array = array("a", "B", "c", "D");

$loop = function($array){
    foreach($array as $ray){
        echo $ray;
    }
};

// you can call that function like this. 

$loop($array);
?>
```

In this case the output would be: `aBcD` after you call it like that.

If you want to just loop a certain part, do it like this:

```
<?php
$array = array("a", "B", "c", "D");

foreach($array as $ray){
?>

<div class="footer">
    <?php echo $ray; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

*Not the cleanest code I've ever done, but it will do the job*

Comment: should i call $loop($array); ? not $loop($ray); ? because i need value of $ray

Comment: @Avos In my example above, you call the loop like that. Yes. An `Anonymous function` is a function in a variable. You call the function through that variable. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to apply that function... I'll let you know the result

Comment: the code won't work, because i want to write the code between these "" symbol

Comment: Why does it need to be in a string?

Comment: because I am using email function, at the function the email body should be a string.. and i want to loop the value of the email body..

Comment: You need to do that **BEFORE** you send the email, just an ordinay `for` loop in that case. You can't do that after the fact.